# More Character Dialog in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I love hearing the voices of the classes in TF2, but I feel like I never hear many of the sound clips. Is there any way to increase the incidence of character speech in TF2? Mods and such are ok.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way without mods or actually looking into the game files is to use the 'x' and 'z' in corolation with '1-9'. Your key-pressing will look something like this: 'x' + '2'; which produces the 'Spy!' sound file. There ~20 more available clips. You cant hear the clips like the domination lines, but there are probably mods for that. Hope it helps.